# How to use 'either or'?

Tags: conjunctions, conditional-constructions

> If you don't tell the truth, you will be beaten.

If this sentence is to be changed by using 'either … or', which one is correct?

> 1. Either tell the truth or you will be beaten.
> 2. Either you tell the truth or you will be beaten.

Answer (score 3):

Either of your versions is acceptable—clauses in different 'moods' (declarative, imperative, interrogative) may be coordinated.

With the imperative version you may also omit the *either*:

> Tell the truth or you'll be beaten.

And you can cast *both* clauses in the imperative:

> Tell the truth or be beaten.